# Toggling with respect to react hooks doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement the following side toggle component.

I am maintaining two components to handle the flow. One being ToggleItems and the other being ToggleItem.

The open-close icons are being added using classes `left`, `right` for the header. And for the children, it's `up`, `down`. There is a parent state maintained and that gets passed down to the children.

I see on a child's up arrow and down arrow click, all the children get toggled. Can someone help me rectify this issue?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-3enpm

Comment: The first issue is if you need a different state for each arrow, then it follows you'd need a different _state_ for each arrow. This can be accomplished by using an array of booleans for `headerExpand` instead of just a single boolean value.

Comment: It also seems like you're maintaining redundant state inside the `ToggleItem` component. You don't need the `itemClick` state... it's all managed in the parent component. If you need to, pass the change handler to the child

Comment: @Nick, would you help me by ediitng this snippet?

Comment: passing state up and down is not a good idea on the long run. when you need more than one component using the same piece of state you should se a store like Redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent component can be updated to maintain an array of boolean values: one for each toggle.

Next, you'll want to pass down an index-specific change handler to each toggle component to make sure it's capable of changing the state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ToggleItem from "./ToggleItem";

type ToggleState = Record<number, boolean>;

const ToggleItems: React.FC = () => {
  const [containerExpand, setContainerExpand] = useState(false);
  const [headerExpand, setHeaderExpand] = useState<ToggleState>({});

  const createToggler = (index) => () => {
    const newHeaderExpand = { ...headerExpand };
    newHeaderExpand[index] = !newHeaderExpand[index];
    setHeaderExpand(newHeaderExpand);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`holder root-${!containerExpand ? "right" : "left"}`}
      onClick={() => setContainerExpand(!containerExpand)}
    >
<div style={{display: containerExpand ? "block" : "none"}} className="body">
        {[0, 1, 2, 3].map((i) => (
          <ToggleItem
            key={i}
            headerExpand={headerExpand[i] || false}
            toggle={createToggler(i)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ToggleItems;
```

Finally, you can change the child component to remove the redundant state and be able to toggle the parent state:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ToggleItem: React.FC = ({ headerExpand, toggle }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <table className="legend-group-header-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td className="group-icon-holder">Sample1</td>
              <td className="group-count-holder">3</td>
              <td className="group-toggle-icon-holder">
                <span
                  className={`group-toggle-icon ${
                    headerExpand ? "up" : "down"
                  }`}
                  onClick={() => toggle()}
                ></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      {headerExpand && (
        <div className="legend-group-body">
          <div> Test1 2hrs ago</div>
          <div> Test2 2hrs ago</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ToggleItem;
```

Comment: Correct! The items can (and probably should be dynamic). You can create them using a loop

Comment: I'll change it so it's dynamic

Comment: Alright, it's updated

Comment: thanks. I guess you forgot to add the outer div in the parent component and its toggle handler? For `right` and `left` classes. I need them to add the icons for the topmost header

Comment: I updated it to use a different piece of state for the container's expanded state to get that effect

Comment: You just need to conditionally display the content somehow based on the `containerExpand` variable. Something like this will work https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-3enpm